# C# Windows forms - launching process in a loop

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Im launching an .exe file from inside a loop, the .exe file will terminate itself when it finishes its job, so I have a check for that (P_Exited).

1. Question is how to launch the .exe file inside the loop and keep the UI alive/active so I can see some feedback - like how many times did it pass etc. (I assume some threading would help)
2. Question is that I sometimes need to exit the process earlier (before it terminates itself) for example I need to exit the process after 3 hours of running, how can I achieve that?

Thanks for helping me out

```
public void start_opt()
    {


        int pocetEas = eas_list.CheckedItems.Count;

        log.Clear();

        string[] EA_pole = nazevEA.ToArray();
        string[] INI_pole = nazevINI.ToArray();


        for (int i = 0; i < pocetEas; i++)
        {
            DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;

            log.AppendText(localDate + " - Optimalizace " + (i + 1) + " z " + pocetEas.ToString() + " spuštěna \r\n");

            try
            {
                Process P = new Process();
                P.Exited += new EventHandler(P_Exited);
                P.StartInfo.FileName = @Properties.Settings.Default.mt5_terminal;
                P.StartInfo.Arguments = "/config:" + Properties.Settings.Default.mt5_appdata + "\\MQL5\\files\\" + INI_pole[i];
                P.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                P.Start();

            }
            catch
            {
            }
            if (hotovychEA < i + 1)
            {
                timer1.Start();
                while (hotovychEA < i + 1)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

```
private void P_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e){
        hotovychEA++;        
   }
```

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep`, you are on the UI thread (I believe). Make your function `async` and use `await Task.Delay()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private async Task RunProcAsync(Process proc)
{
  await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    proc.Start();
    var exited = proc.WaitForExit(10000); // Set required Timeout here
    if (!exited) { proc.Kill(); }
  });
}
```

Add the given method to your code and replace `p.Start()` with `await RunProcAsync(p);`. This should kill your process if its running over a particular period of time and also keep the UI active